# How can I set PATH variable using QT?

Tags: c++, qt4, environment-variables

How can I get and set PATH variable using QT 4.8? I know I can get PATH variable values using getenv from the STL but don't know how to set it using STL or any Qt based method?

If QT has a function for it, I would like to know and use it rather than going and using Windows API for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use setenv from stdlib.h to set PATH to a new value.

```
setenv("PATH","/new/path/value",1)
```

However, this is a non-standard extension to the standard headers, and will only affect sub-processes spawned by the calling process. In order to change environment variables for all new processes spawned, a system-specific method must be used. For windows, the PATH variable can be changed in the

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

registry key. This will make sure the PATH is set for all new processes, and will apply over a reboot.

Comment: Thank you very much :) i didnt know that we have setenv at STL!.
But do you know if we have some thing Qt based? if there is'nt anything like it i accept his as answer.

Comment: It seems that you can use [QProcessEnviroment](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocessenvironment.html) to set the environment of processes spawned using [QProcess](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qprocess.html).

Comment: Thanks, I need a machine wide permission ( i mean pertaining to the whole OS, not the process itself ) will it still get me going?

Comment: If you need the `PATH` to be changed system wide, then you need to use the Windows API to add the desired change to the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment` [registry key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636055/how-to-modify-the-path-variable-definitely-through-the-command-line-in-windows), which will  change the path for any new applications launched. The changes you make will also survive a reboot.

Comment: Thanks, then would you add this last comment as well to the answer ? and also mention _putenv() as well (since setenv seems not to be in standard headers! couldnt find it!)

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to my friend Mr. Toosi, you can set environment variable for current process using `qputenv("key", "value")` and get it using `qgetenv("key")`.
This works on Qt 5.5.0 too :)

Answer (score 2):

I worked with the `Registry` value using this code:

**Include:**

```
#include <windows.h>
```

**To read:**

```
QSettings setting( "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Control\\Session Manager\\Environment", QSettings::NativeFormat );
QString pathVal = setting.value("Path", "no-path").toString();
```

**To write:**

```
setting.setValue( "Path", path );
SendMessageA( HWND_BROADCAST, WM_SETTINGCHANGE, 0, (LPARAM)"Environment" );
```

This way I get the actual `Path` value without reloading the program and write the value broadcasting the change to all processes.

Couldn't realize first how to use `SendMessage` from this answer:
[How to modify the PATH variable definitely through the command line in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3636055/how-to-modify-the-path-variable-definitely-through-the-command-line-in-windows/3637349#3637349).
I thought I should create a `Win32` app in **Visual Studio** and then send this message inside of it.

But this function should be called just after the registry changed. So I could edit the registry value manually and then press a button which called the `SendMessageA` and the `Path` updated.

---

BTW, there is `SendMessage` macro which calls `SenMessageW` function but it didn't work and the `Path` didn't change. Don't know what the `A` means but it changes the variable.