# how to specify search directory for source code build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, build

I am trying to install Jom (http://wiki.qt.io/Jom) for C++. When I type in qmake -r in cmd, I get the error `Project MESSAGE: Cannot build jom with Qt version 4.8.7.` `Project ERROR: Use at least Qt 5.2.0.`. This is because I have PyQt version 4.8.7 and Qt version 5.8.0 both installed. When building Jom, Jom searches for in the wrong Qt folder. How can I fix this?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17490489/how-can-i-set-path-variable-using-qt) answer your question?

Comment: I have tried adding Qt 5.8.0 to environment variables but Jom still searches for Qt in the PyQt folder. I'm a beginner in C++ and cmd commands, what can I do?

Comment: jom is always there with standard Qt package so you don't really need to build it. It is where qmake is.

Comment: @AlexanderVX `jom.exe` is distributed with Qt Creator, not with Qt. It is not where qmake is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have multiple version of Qt installed, you also have multiple version of qmake. You can check which qmake you are running by using `where qmake` on Windows, it will output a list of qmake executable available in your path, the first one in the list will be the one executed when running `qmake`.

For instance:

```
C:\>where qmake
C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe
C:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe
```

If the first one, is not the one you want, you can run it by using its complete path:

```
C:\>C:\Qt\5.6\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe -version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.6.2 in C:/Qt/5.6/msvc2015/lib
```

---

If the qmake and Qt version you want is not in your PATH, you can use the scripts provided by Qt to setup a valid environment. These are available in the Start menu as `Qt 5.8 64-bit for Desktop (MSVC 2015)` (change according to your installation), or you can use them directly by executing `qtenv2.bat` (e.g `C:\Qt\5.8\msvc2015\bin\qtenv2.bat`).

If you are using MinGW you are all set, but if you are using MSVC you need also to run `vcvarsall.bat`, which can be found in your Visual installation folder.