# Adding to the PATH on Windows in node.js - sending WM_SETTINGCHANGE?

Tags: node.js, windows, path, environment-variables

I'm writing an installation script (in node.js, specificially slush/gulp although I don't think that matters) that sets up some common tools on our developer machines.

For one of these tools, I need to modify the PATH environment variable on Windows machines.

So far the best way I've found to do this is using the [winreg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/winreg) package to modify the Registry directly (in `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment\Path`), which works great (aside from the need to run the entire install script in an elevanted command prompt).

However, it requires either a machine restart for the new PATH to take effect (not even just opening a new command prompt, as it would usually), OR sending the user into their system preferences to just open up the Environment Variables dialog box and click OK.

[This detailed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3637349/1982136) covers some of what needs to happen beneath the hood when you change an environment variable programmatically. I'm assuming the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message ([details here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms725497.aspx)) is sent to the system when clicking OK in that Environment Variables dialog box.

So, how could I go about sending the `WM_SETTINGCHANGE` message from node.js? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I can offer non-native solution (not sure if native exists). It updated the value for me without restarts.

I'm talking about `reg.exe` tool that is shipped with Windows starting at least from Windows XP.

The algorithm:

## 1. Form a command for update, e.g.:

```js
const scriptContent = `REG ADD HKCU\\Environment /v Path /t REG_SZ /d "${newPath}" /f`
```

- **HKCU\Environment** - is the path to your variable in registry,
- **Path** - name of the variable to update,
- **REG_SZ** - type of the variable,
- **"${newPath}"** - new PATH contents (fully old content with added new paths. Using quotes just in case we have white spaces there),
- **/f** - force rewrite (basically, this command is for creation. So, if this variable doesn't exist, it will be created, otherwise - overwritten).

## 2. Write this contents to a script file, e.g. **script.bat**:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const scriptPath = 'script.bat';
fs.writeFile(scriptPath, scriptContent);
```

## 3. Execute the script file:

```js
const child_process = require("child_process");
child_process.exec(scriptPath);
```